# How to do an equivalent of the PHP's is_dir in PHP FTP mode?

Tags: php, ftp

I'm making a simple FTP client in PHP, and I'd like to use an equivalent of `is_dir`.
Basically I have:

```
$ftp_connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server,$ftp_port,$timeout) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
/* other things here */
$documents = ftp_rawlist($ftp_connection,ftp_pwd($ftp_connection));
foreach($documents as $current_document){
   /* if is_dir($current_document) do something */
      echo $current_document;
      echo "<br>";
}
```

Obviously it does not work, and I tried to resolve in this way:

```
if($current_document[0]=='d') /* do something */;
```

And it works fine, but I'm not sure it's a correct way, thus, I'd like to use `ftp_nlist` rather than `ftp_rawlist`.

Comment: If it is an open-source project I would like to contribute, I have already made a PHP FTP library https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-client, I would be happy to share my knowledge with other people.

Comment: @PainNagatu Thank you so much! I starred your repo on Github, my project is open source too (https://github.com/xfarrow/FTP_HTTPmiddleware) but I have to warn you that is kinda a personal project to acquire knowledge in PHP, maybe if you see my code you'll freak out xD
I'll check your library and I'll be surely happy to study it and use it, thank you!

Comment: Thank you! believe me, I was just like you, I was writing a plain poor code most of the time, but if you spend a lot of time to read and learn code of other people, you'll see improvements in every day, however, I've checked your project and I would be very happy to contribute, thanks!